# How to convert this method to catch the inserted id?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form and I'm inserting values in the button click event like this

```
Candidate CanObj = new Candidate(txtName.Text);
if (new CandidateOP().saveCandidate(CanObj))
{
    MessageBox.Show("NEW candidate details added");
}
```

this is my business layer method.

```
public Boolean saveCandidate(Candidate CanObj)
{
    string query6 = "EXEC insertToCand01'" + CanObj.NIC + "'";
    return (new DataAccessLayer().executeNonQueries(query6));
}
```

This is my data access layer method

```
public Boolean executeNonQueries(string query02)
{
    Boolean flag = false;
    SqlConnection con = null;
    SqlCommand com = null;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.makeConnection());
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand(query02, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        flag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        flag = false;
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

This is the query inside my stored procedure to insert.
In my table the ID is set to auto increment.

```
INSERT INTO Candidate (User_Name) VALUES (@Uname);
```

Now I want to display the inserted ID to be displayed when it's inserted.
So I changed the query like this.

```
INSERT INTO Candidate (User_Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.User_ID VALUES (@Uname);
```

I want to change my data access layer and business layer to get the value back 
How to change my data access layer to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't like how you wasting new instances :(

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick but important note: you should really use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection problems, and also using a proper ORM system.

About your concrete question: call your procedure with ExecuteScalar, instead of ExecuteNonQuery, and return the generated id from your stored procedure.

You don't actually need an SP, you can just do a `select scope_identity()` for example. Or you could use an output parameter in your SP. But just returning a scalar is the simplest way.

Comment: @fejecjoco Correct me if I'm wrong, as i read this is the best method, because if you are using parallel execution plan this is the best method. About the sql injections. Yes I know about it. In this it is unnecessary as it is for my private use. Please don't ONLY focus on that. Please raise your concern about converting the method.

Comment: I didn't only focus on that. I wrote about ExecuteScalar, I believe it is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Candidate CanObj = new Candidate(txtName.Text);
int id = new CandidateOP().saveCandidate(CanObj);
/* You have **id** here, and you can use it. */
if (id >= 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("NEW candidate details added");
}
```

Business layer:

```
public Boolean saveCandidate(Candidate CanObj)
{
    string query6 = "EXEC insertToCand01'" + CanObj.NIC + "'";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeNonQueries(query6);
}
```

and your access layer:

```
public int executeNonQueries(string query02)
{
    long id = -1;
    SqlConnection con = null;
    SqlCommand com = null;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.makeConnection());
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand(query02, con);
        SqlParameter returnParameter = com.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        id = (int) returnParameter.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        id = -1;
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: @ Ali Sepehri.Kh How do you get the id in the form level in a variable?

Comment: Could you kindly include a code example how to catch it to an int type variable in form level.

Comment: @Sahil: Sorry I wasn't available. I edited my answer. Do you mean this?

Comment: Yeah something like that. Business layer method should be int to do that. I did that and tried too, but it's not working. Giving 0 as the new id.